# Shorter keystroke than :w in Vim, to save without exit?

Tags: vim, keyboard-shortcuts, vi

I want to save my opened file *without exit* in vim using shortcut keystrokes, the way we use

<kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>ZZ</kbd> to save and exit.

Does anyone know how to do it?

Comment: you mean shorter than `:w`?

Comment: You could put `nnoremap ZS :w<cr>` into your `.vimrc`.

Comment: @Toothort thanks for help :) I did the same ..it worked !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Toothrot [answered this in the comments](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/346782/shorter-keystroke-then-w-in-vi-to-save-without-exit#comment613690_346782):

> You could put `nnoremap ZS :w<cr>` into your `.vimrc`

Comment: Alternatively, you can map it to `nnoremap ZS :up<cr>`. (`:update` saves the file only if it was changed) It behaves better it you have some scripts that trigger when the file is saved.